# How to prevent data rewrite in cloud firestore. Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am making an app where I had coded a function which will authenticate user using google sign in. Then it will add user Email, Name & UID to cloud firestore. Everything works fine. But when I re-login with same google account a new document is made in firestore everytime. How to prevent this recreation of diffrent document every time?

Comment: simpliest option - set empty list for `mergeFields` in your `set` method. Like so: `_documentReference.set(data, SetOptions(mergeFields: []))` , but to check if you should make write operation before like suggested in answer is better option, because firestore crud is not free.

Answer (score 2):

When you sign in users using Google, there is a property isNew in additionalUserInfo returned in the response. You can check the if user is new, if yes then add the documents else don't.

```
Future<FirebaseUser> _signIn() async {
 try {
  GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = await googleSignIn.signIn();
  GoogleSignInAuthentication gSA = await googleSignInAccount.authentication;
  final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
    accessToken: gSA.accessToken,
    idToken: gSA.idToken,
  );
  AuthResult authResult = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
  if (authResult.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser) {
    //User logging in for the first time
    // Add data to Firestore
  }
  else {
    //not a new user
    //Just redirect to main activity
  }
} catch (e) {
  print(e.message);
}}
```

Other option would be using [Firebase Auth Triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events) for cloud function which will run a function to add data to Firestore when a new user is created. This is totally your decision which way suits your needs.